# magento2 how to update tier price programmatically, including value type?

Tags: magento2, tierprice

I am able to add tier prices using csv

```
$this->tierPrice->add($sku, $customerGroupId, $price, $qty);
```

but it is taking "`value_type`" as Fixed, I want to dynamically give the value for "`value_type`"

Comment: https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/add-update-product-tier-price-programmatically-magento-2/ check the article for more details.

Comment: I'm also looking for a solution to update *tier price* without call `save()` method. So, I used @embed0 suggested solution but exception accured: > The data was invalid. Verify the data and try again. in /vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/TierPriceManagement.php:99 Can you please specified the expected result for `$productTierPrice` argument of `add()` method?

Answer (score 2):

I used Rakesh Jesadiya article information and done some debugging to create more "elegant" solution for percentage_value tier price type. Here is my code:

```
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductTierPriceInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductTierPriceInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ScopedProductTierPriceManagementInterface;

class ProductPriceListsResolver
{
    /**
     * @var ScopedProductTierPriceManagementInterface
     */
    private $tierPriceManagement;
    /**
     * @var ProductTierPriceInterface
     */
    private $productTierPriceFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ScopedProductTierPriceManagementInterface $tierPriceManagement,
        ProductTierPriceInterfaceFactory $productTierPriceFactory
    ) {

        $this->tierPriceManagement = $tierPriceManagement;
        $this->productTierPriceFactory = $productTierPriceFactory;
    }

    public function resolve()
    {
        $sku = 'sku_83519'; //Product sku
        $customerGroupId = 6; //premium group id
        $price = 50.00;
        $qty = 1.00;

        /** @var ProductTierPriceInterface $productTierPrice */
        $productTierPrice = $this->productTierPriceFactory->create();
        $productTierPrice->setCustomerGroupId($customerGroupId)
            ->setQty($qty)
            ->setValue(20.00);

        $extensionAttributes = $productTierPrice->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extensionAttributes->setPercentageValue(20.00);
        $productTierPrice->setExtensionAttributes($extensionAttributes);
        try {
            $this->tierPriceManagement->add($sku, $productTierPrice);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new $e;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I done the same by doing

```
$product_obj = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($prod_id);
    $tierPrices[] = array(
                                 'website_id'  => 0,
                                 'cust_group'  => 1,
                                 'price_qty'   => $qty,
                                 'price'       => $price,
                                 'percentage_value'  => $percentage);
                          $product_obj->setTierPrice($tierPrices);
                        $product_obj->save(); 
Here in the above array   `percentage_value` is given for the price range having discount type.
```

Answer (score 0):

@embed0's solution is largely correct, however may result in the issue @Samuele experienced "The data was invalid. Verify the data and try again.". Our solution on this was to floatval() both the qty and price values.